# Генерация случайных чисел. Почему среднее не ноль?

Tags: c++, случайные-числа, теория-вероятностей, генерация-случайных-данных

Допустим, программа моделирует случайное блуждание точки на прямой, каждое следующее положение отличается от предыдущего на случайный вектор значение которого [-1, 1], в начале точка находится в нуле.

Вроде бы, при большом числе шагов, среднее значение координаты должно стремиться к нулю, но так не получается, почему?

Например, b должно стремиться к нулю (среднее b вычисляю как сумму всех случайных координат, поделенную на количество шагов(1000)):

```
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    double a = 0, b, sum;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        a += (double)rand() * 2 / RAND_MAX - 1;
        sum += a;
    }
    b = sum / 1000.0; 
    cout << b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Но у меня, почему-то, получается не ноль

Comment: чему равно RAND_MAX ?

Comment: @BogdanBida, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/RAND_MAX/

Comment: Запустил код на [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/tw7RJX), число `b` получилось даже отрицательное..

Comment: а что в итоге выводит? чем вам так результат не нравится? слишком далеко от 0, или просто есть какой то остаток?

Comment: И какие результаты запусков у вас?

Comment: @entithat, вполне ожидаемо (впрочем, я спрашивал автора вопроса) (хм, пока набивал он уже удалил комментарий)

Comment: @avp, Ну ответ автора будет примерно тот же :D

Comment: прощу прощения, неправильно в первый раз написал программу, теперь вопрос сформулирован корректно

Comment: Зачем на 1000 делить, если вы итак конечную координату в sum получаете? И sum=0 наверно нужно инициализировать.

Answer (score 5):

Точный 0 у вас не получится - просто потому, что числа случайные. Это будет величина, *близкая* к нулю, но не ноль.

Потому что иначе, если вы получили 0.5, то вторым числом должно выпасть -0.5? :)

Скажем так - сумма может быть любой (ну, до 1000 :), но вероятность получить сумму в некотором диапазоне от x до x+dx резко снижается с увеличением x. Но не является нулевой.

Более подробно здесь, боюсь, рассказать не получится. Возьмите какую-то книжку по теорверу и матстатистике, и почитайте...

Comment: прощу прощения, неправильно в первый раз написал программу, теперь вопрос сформулирован корректно, перечитайте

Comment: В новой программе вы вообще никак не инициализируете значение `sum`, оно может быть в принципе любым...

Comment: Да, и кстати - насколько я помню, при случайном блуждании теория говорит, что за N шагов уход от начальной точки пропорционален sqrt(N)...

Comment: результат будет зависить от  генерации случайных чисел. Если  в 
результате  (double)rand() * 2 / RAND_MAX - 1   вы получите больше положителных чисел, и  их значения будут превосходить абсолютным значениям отрицательных (или наоборот), то вы в итоге не получите  среднее значение близкого к нулю.